# Python NLTK: fdist.plot error

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to make a plot of frequencies for the top 50 words from a text file but this is the error message I am getting.

```
s-10', 'logan', 'jacksonville', 'brokerage', 'brickman', 'mount', 'wireless', 'p
hillips', 'advisor', 'okavango', 'portfolio', 'sill', 'weddings', 'share', 'para
legal']

>>> fdist1.plot(50)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 229, in plot
import pylab
ImportError: No module named 'pylab'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 231, in plot
raise ValueError('The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pyl
ab). '
ValueError: The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab). See h
ttp://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/
```

My professor's sample code does not say anything about importing a pylab package. I tried to download it anyways and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: Is your question: [how to install `matplotlib` Python package](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Plotting a distribution requires matplotlib.

See the relevant lines of [FreqDist.plot()](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html):

```
try:
    from matplotlib import pylab   
except ImportError:
    raise ValueError('The plot function requires matplotlib to be installed.'
                     'See http://matplotlib.org/')
```